# which event receiver adaptor should be used for android - siddhi application for simulating sensor based case scenario

Tags: wso2, health-monitoring, siddhi

I have a case scenario where  health sensors are sending streams to siddhi-android, as I don't have real health sensors  so I use an event simulator, now question is which input adaptor should I use for this scenario and why

```
Email Event Receiver
File-tail Event Receiver
HTTP Event Receiver
JMS Event Receiver
Kafka Event Receiver
MQTT Event Receiver
SOAP Event Receiver
WebSocket Event Receiver
WebSocket Local Event Receiver
WSO2Event Event Receiver
```

**I am confused between MQTT and WebSocket**

I think MQTT has something to do with IP changes that phone is going to make when it will connect and disconnect to network, then Mosquito broker will take care of that. On the other hand, I am not sure if `WebSocket` is the right choice. Also as I am using siddhi 4.0 I am not sure if I can use these [extentions](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/extensions/) in android.

I have used `tcp` extension in android studio

```
implementation files ('libs/siddhi-io-tcp-2.0.13.jar');
annotationProcessor files ('libs/siddhi-io-tcp-2.0.13.jar')
```

but the annotations are not working

[image]

not sure if tcp is right choice either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile devices, MQTT will be a better option as it can also handle connection failures effectively.

You can do that with siddhi-io-mqtt[1] adopter.

[1] https://wso2-extensions.github.io/siddhi-io-mqtt/